# if two matrices have same four fundamental subspaces, is one multiple of other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If two matrices A and B have same four fundamental subspaces (rowspace, columnspace, nullspace, left nullspace) is it always true that A=cB for constant c?

It might help, that it can be proved (simply by contradiction method) that given condition is equivalent to $rref(A)=rref(B)$ and $rref(A^T)=rref(B^T)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$